# Does there exist a differentiable conservative vector field with non - vanishing curl?

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

I know that for a continuously differentiable vector field $F: D \subset R^3 \to R $ where $D$ is an simply connected subset of $R^3$ to be conservative, it must satisy $curl(F)(P) = 0$ at every $P \ \epsilon \ D$.

But $curl(F)(P) = 0$ for every $P \ \epsilon \ D$ is a necessary condition for the vector field to be consevative only when the vector field is continuously differentiable. So what I want to ask is the follwing:

Does there exist a conservative vector field  which is differentiable but not continuously differentiable and whose $curl \ne 0$ at every point in its domain? If not can we show that a differentiable vector field must always have a vanishing curl?

Comment: The second paragraph is only true if $D$ is simply connected. If there are non-contractible loops in $D$ then there exist continuously differentiable non-conservative vector fields with curl 0.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question and impose the condition of simple connectedness on D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to counterexamples in the context of Clairaut's theorem, i.e., examples of functions where the order of partial derivatives may not be interchanged. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity) has an example in two variables with a nice picture.

One could adapt such an example to establish nonvanishing curl at a single point: add a dummy third variable $z$ and consider the gradient of that function. A gradient is always conservative, but the $z$-component of the curl of that gradient is nonzero at the origin.

Such examples do not work for constructing a nonvanishing curl in the entire domain, however; distribution theory shows that partial derivatives can be freely interchanged up to a set of volume 0.

Comment: Yes so can you give a example of a function which has non - vanishing curl at at least one point

Comment: Done; hope you like the link